# Firebase Tasks: sign in + create account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app works with Firebase Authentication. And when user starts app I need to add new user in Firebase, but I have 3 state:

1. There is no account
2. There is an account, but the user signed out
3. There is an account and the user signed in

For these 3 states, I must do the next:

1. create account in Firebase + log in my Database (at the same time)
   then sign in Firebase
2. sign in Firebase + log in my Database (at the
   same time)
3. log in my Database

How to make the first item correctly using Tasks? How to control errors?

I determine whether the signed user or not, using:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    firebaseAuthUser = true;
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    firebaseAuthUser = false;
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FirebaseUI-Android to gracefully handle those situations for you.
It's really simple to implement! Please check it [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).

You can check all FirebaseUI features [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: Henrique, thank you. I read about FirebaseUI, this library has the same problem. "Tasks" library helps to start some tasks at the same time, But there are three problems I need to solve: 1) different sequence of the tasks which depends on state of user; 2) I must wait and monitor when two tasks finished correctly then 3) Starts the third task using continueWithTask  or may be better using Listener I don't know